# Alarm Functionality In ReactNative For Android And iOS

Tags: react-native, alarm

I want to make app that play music every day at specific time (for example : 07:00) even if the app in background or turned off

I had done it in android with `Java & Android SDK` using `Alarm Manager` , i'm looking for something like that for ReactNative

I had searched for libraries but i did not found useful resources

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check this out https://github.com/wmcmahan/react-native-calendar-events , The alarms associated with the calendar event, as an array of alarm objects.

Comment: Is that just a short alarm (i.e. a push notification sound)? I am looking for an alarm that you have to manually stop/snooze.

Comment: it is a calendar event that use and support alarm like a reminder, you can check https://github.com/smartliang/react-native-alarm for a full functional alarm @MichaelL. the usage and example of the library will be updated as soon as the owner accept my P.R